# Does collections.Counter eat a generator while counting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have been looking at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

I am using the following (simplified) code:

```
choices = ['foo', 'bar']

def generator(n=100000000):
  yield random.choice(choices)

counts = collections.Counter(generator())
```

Now my question, in my implementation `Counter` takes a generator as input. To first convert the generator to a list would take way too much space in memory.

So I wonder if `collections.Counter` first converts the data to a list and then 'counts' or it 'eats' the generator while counting.

If it first converts the data to a list. How would I best go about implementing it without converting it to a list.

Comment: As far as I know the `Counter` eats the generator and counts meanwhile.

Comment: There is no `itertools.Counter` only `collections.Counter`

Comment: You're right. I changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the iterable you pass in (be it a generator or another iterable object) is *not* converted to a list.

There is no need to convert the iterable; counting is done as you iterate. The implementation is essentially the same as:

```
counts = {}
for element in generator():
    if element in counts:
        counts[element] += 1
    else:
        counts[element] = 1
```

but a `Counter()` object does this much faster (the counting code is implemented in C).